# Xcode: No copy of xxx.app/xxxDev found locally, reading from memory

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios4, xcode4

I decided to make a separate target for my development app using Xcode 4.1. I duplicated the target, changed the bundle ID, made a new scheme. The original target was called "xxx" and the new one is "xxxDev". 
The app builds, runs and debugs (sort of) correctly on the iPhone/iPad. Both versions; Dev and non-dev are on the iPhone. Only two problems:
1) when debugging, every so often xCode is not able to attach to the process it just launched.
2) I always get the warning 
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/jon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-eesunloavphkaraezppecayjklqw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.app/xxxDev (file not found).

The file is correctly built under 
/Users/jon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-eesunloavphkaraezppecayjklqw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxxDev.app/xxxDev

For some reason when running the debugger it is somehow holding on to the old build directory "xxx.app" and I can't find how I can change this. The scheme I am using points to the xxxDev.app executable.
I've grepped every possible file in the various directories and found nothing.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same thing with XCode 4.2b5 last week-end. Reinstalling XCode did the trick for me.

Comment: As far as I know, the latest version of Xcode is 4.1b48110 of Jul 20th.